# ¿Como hacer Binding a la propiedad "Icon" de FontAwesome UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, font-awesome, icons

Tengo esta galeria de iconos que descargue para mi proyecto de UWP

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome.UWP/

Necesito hacer un Binding a la propiedad de Icon asi que el xaml lo llamo asi:

```
xmlns:fa="using:FontAwesome.UWP"
```

y en el grid o en un stackpanel lo llamo asi:

```
<StackPanel>
   <Viewbox>
       <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Industry"/>
   </Viewbox>
</StackPanel>
```

¿Como le puedo hacer binding, pensaba que enviandole un string funcionaba directo pero no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, @Karel me dio la idea la solucione:

Primero cree una clase donde convertire el texto en icon:

```
public class TextToIcon : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType = null, object parameter = null, string language = null)
    {
        FontAwesomeIcon item;
        if (value != null && Enum.TryParse(value.ToString(), out item))
            return item;
        else
            return FontAwesomeIcon.None;
     }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Luego lo agrego a un Diccionario de recursos en XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="using:Proyecto.Converters"> <!-- este es el using del namespace de la clase convertidora -->

    <c:ImageToVisible       x:Key="ImageToVisible.conv"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Y ahora en la page, donde estoy editando la vista hago asi:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Viewbox MaxHeight="35" Width="70">
          <fa:FontAwesome Icon="{x:Bind Icono, Converter={StaticResource TextToIcon.conv}}" Foreground="#f1c40f"/>
    </Viewbox>
</StackPanel>
```

Y listo queda full el Binding en el Icon

Answer (score 1):

Para UWP es un poco diferente a WPF. En WPF existe la posibilidad de asignar un binding path que sea string, pero en UWP el tipo es un enum. Así que una posible solución es declarar la propiedad del viewmodel que enlazaras de tipo `FontAwesome.UWP.FontAwesomeIcon`.

### Opción 1

```
private FontAwesomeIcon _iconName;
public FontAwesomeIcon IconName
{
    get => _iconName;
    private set
    {
        if (value == _iconName) return;
        _iconName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Y suponiendo que tienes en namespace `fa` registrado para el nuget de `FontAwesome.UWP`. Algo como esto:

```
xmlns:fa="using:FontAwesome.UWP"
```

Entonces puedes enlazarlo así en la vista:

```
<StackPanel>
   <Viewbox>
       <fa:FontAwesome Icon="{Binding IconName}" />
   </Viewbox>
</StackPanel>
```

### Opción 2: Usando un `IValueConverter`:

La otra posibilidad es pasarle un `string` (como estabas pensando) y usar [converter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter) para transformar ese valor a la instancia correcta de `FontAwesomeIcon`.

La primera es más fácil, siempre que puedas obtener los iconos que precisas directo del enum, pero si necesitas ayuda con esta otra... avisa :-)

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: uy graxcias, voy a probar y si algo comentare. gracias

Comment: listo lo solucione por la segunda opcion